# Angular 4: Get ViewContainerRef of inserted dynamic HTML element

Tags: angular

I am inserting dynamic page content like this in angular 4:

```
<app-component>
    <main [innerHTML]="dynamicHTML"></main>
</app-component>
```

Which will render to:

```
<app-component>
    <main>
        <div>
            <div id="insertionPoint">
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</app-component>
```

Is it possible to get a `ViewContainerRef` of the `div#insertionPoint` that has been dynamically added. The `div#insertionPoint` could be anywhere in a large HTML document that is loaded into `<main>`.

I would like to use the `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` along with the `ComponentFactoryResolver` to insert an Angular Component inside the dynamic HTML.

Comment: No you can't. There is alternative option `factory.create(injector, [], element)` where `element` is specific dom element